# Unable to insert into cloud Google SQL through endpoints

Tags: maven, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have created a Maven Endpoint project and I want to connect my project with google SQL on cloud. I have already created a database on cloud and I am trying to insert into that database through my Maven Endpoint project but when I execute my Endpoint Project, I am unable to insert into the database. I am Working with Endpoints for the first time and hence I cant figure out where I am going wrong .Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

The code below is my Endpoint Project code For connecting and inserting into google SQL on cloud.

```
package com.syncing.SuperMarket;  

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.sql.DriverManager; 
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

@Api(
name = "supermarket",
version = "v1",
scopes = {Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE},
clientIds = {Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,Constants.IOS_CLIENT_ID},
audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE}
)
public class Sync {
  /**
   * Insert a row into cloud Google SQL Database
   * @param no_of_products
   * @param total_amt
   * @param u_id
   * @return
   */ 
      @ApiMethod(name = "insertData")
      public void getPurchaseDetails(@Named("no_of_products") int no_of_products,@Named("total_amt") int total_amt,@Named("u_id") int u_id)
      {
              try {
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.GoogleDriver");
                  java.sql.Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:google:mysql://app-id:instance-id/db_name?user=username&password=password");
                  String query = "INSERT INTO purchase (no_of_products,total_amt,u_id) VALUES (?,?,?)";
                  CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall(query);
                  stmt.setInt(1, no_of_products);
                  stmt.setInt(2, total_amt);
                  stmt.setInt(3, u_id);
                  stmt.execute();
                  stmt.close();
                  conn.close();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }      
      }

}
```

Comment: I assume this is running on App Engine? Does the existing code sample (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/) work for you?

Comment: Yes its running on App Engine. No I have not tried the Servlet code example yet. Is there anything wrong with my code? I am just trying to insert a single entry in my database to check whether its working properly or not. But when i try to execute my API in explorer, Under 'Response' its displays a message saying '204 No Content'